# Javascript setTimeout not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small function:

```
function showVotingModal(e) {

    var $collector = $("#vote-collector");

    setTimeout(function () {

        $collector.addClass("open");
    }, 5000);

    $collector.find(".description").text($(this).data("desc"));
    $collector.attr("data-id", "15");

}
```

The idea is to show the #vote-collector panel after a delay of 5 seconds and populate some further data withing the panel.

The above code works, however the code below doesn't.

```
function showVotingModal(e) {

    setTimeout(function () {
        var $collector = $("#vote-collector");
        $collector.addClass("open");
        $collector.find(".description").text($(this).data("desc"));
        $collector.attr("data-id", "15");

 }, 5000);
    }
```

In this case the 'description' tag isn't populated.

Can anyone throw some light on whether I'm doing something wrong, or does the timeout function simply does not work this way?

Thanks

Comment: what error display ?

Comment: Inside setTimeout callback, `this` refers to `window`. You need to use a closure

Comment: what is the `this` in `$collector.find(".description").text($(this).data("desc"));` . i think its out of scope inside that timeout function.

Comment: 'this', in this case if a clicked '<a>' element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to `bind` the outer scope to the `setTimeout`,

```
 function showVotingModal(e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var $collector = $("#vote-collector");
        $collector.addClass("open");
        $collector.find(".description").text($(this).data("desc"));
        $collector.attr("data-id", "15");
     }.bind(this), 5000);
 }
```

Inside `setTimeout` `this` will be considered as `window` by default.

Or you can use the other signature of `setTimeout` that accepts additional parameters after delay,

```
 function showVotingModal(e) {
    setTimeout(function (that) {
        var $collector = $("#vote-collector");
        $collector.addClass("open");
        $collector.find(".description").text($(that).data("desc"));
        $collector.attr("data-id", "15");
     }, 5000, this);
 }
```

Comment: `bind` is a function belongs to `Function prototype`

Comment: Works great and I've been educated too.

Comment: @JohnOhara Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

There is very small mistake in your code you are using this, which is currently pointing to current function scope.
you just need to update your function with below code

```
function showVotingModal(e) {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    var $collector = $("#vote-collector");
    $collector.addClass("open");
    $collector.find(".description").text($(self).data("desc"));
    $collector.attr("data-id", "15");

 }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue should be with the code `$(this).data("desc")`

this will be pointing to different contexts/objects in the 2 cases u've used.

Try using bind for the setTimeout.